QT 4 LibQXT alternatives for QT6
I am currently trying to port a whole program from QT4 OpenSUSE to QT6 Debian 12.5 Kernal 6.1
The original code makes a lot of use of a QXT extension library, of which I have the following references :
QxtStringSpinBox
QxtTimer
QxtConfigDialog
QxtConfigWidget
QxtGroupBox
QxtToolTip
QxtSignalWaiter
QxtXmlFileLoggerEngine
QxtBasicFileLoggerEngine
QxtLogger
I'm rather stumped with trying to replace these to be able to compile the project, and I'm having difficulty finding the original data.
What would be a QT6 alternative with similar functionality?
Preferably, with the least in-depth code changes.
Thanks in advance,
